# how to commit to different svn branch without switching

Tags: svn, branch, commit

I am working on a code usually in trunk but due to recent changes I had to switch my workspace to a branch.

Is it possible to commit any change in the trunk while working in a branch without actually switching the project to trunk

I basically want to commit changes in both trunk and branch without switching back and forth again and again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer: No

This is why God created `svn switch` in the first place. It allows you to change your underlying branch of your working directory without losing your work.

Think of it this way: How many times has a developer broke something because they've said to themselves *"Hey, I don't have to test this. It's a **minor** change"*?

Even if Subversion allowed you to do what you want, it would still be a bad idea. You'd basically be making changes in a codebase with no real way of making sure they work in the first place. This is why Subversion requires you to have a working directory before you can make changes<sup>*</sup>. How would you test your changes?

If you don't want to use `svn switch` because you don't want to lose your work, you could do the following:

- Copy your entire working directory to another location, then use `svn switch` on one to make that trunk.
- Finish your work on your branch. Commit the changes and note the revision number. Now, either do a `svn co` or `svn switch` to get a trunk working copy. Then use `svn merge -r` to merge your changes into trunk. And, of course, test your changes before committing them.

---

<sup>*</sup>Subversion does allow `mkdir`, `cp`, `mv`, and `rm` to work directly upon a URL, but that's mainly to allow you to manipulate branches without having to create a working directory.

Comment: The short answer: use git

Answer (score 0):

Check out the trunk in a different folder.
Make your changes in the trunk, and check them in.
Then merge them to the branch, and check in the merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can't commit to the path outside of WC URL (see `svn info WCROOT`)

The above rule means - if WC root is at a level, which is common parent of branch and trunk, you can commit into both locations at the same time (branch and trunk will be subdirs inside WC). Common parent is repository-root, in order **do not** checkout the whole repo, you can play with --depth and --setdepth options of commit/update